# Передача двумерного массива в функцию

Tags: массивы, c++

Как я знаю, имя массива и указателя тождественны в С++. Из этого следует, что можно инициализировать указатель, а работать с ним, как с именем массива, добавив индекс (квадратный скобки) или смещение к имени массива и круглые скобки со звёздочкой... Но не в этом суть. Я пробовал ввести передачу в функцию двумерного массива (столбы и строки) - не вышло. Очевидно, что где-то вкралась ошибка.
Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int size1 = 3;
const int size2 = 4;
int arr[size1[size2 = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
    
void arr_fun (int arr[[size2, int size1);

void main ()
{
    arr_fun (arr[[size2, size1);
    system ("pause");
}
void arr_fun (int arr[[size2, size1)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<size2; j++)
        {
    cout<<"arr["<<i<<": "<<arr[i[j<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Хотя бы дайте общие понятия по логике передачи адреса двумерного и более массива в функцию, а дальше я сам попробую написать =)

Comment: @00Brain00, а что происходит (ошибки компиляции)?

Вот тут (в тексте), например, квадратные скобочки всюду не закрыты -- это так и задумано или результат неудачной копипасты?

Comment: Подозреваю, что это после вставки побилось. В начальной версии автор написал теги `[CODE]`.

Comment: Если побилось, то, на первый взгляд, не хватает только типа у второго аргумента (size1) в 

     void arr_fun (int arr[[size2, size1)
     {
       ...

Ну, может еще тип `main()` заменить на `int` (хотя, может быть, в винде и `void` проходит).

Comment: В винде тип возвращаемого значения для c++ не имеет значения, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: То что элементы массива располагается последовательно в памяти, действительно только для статических массивов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: "имя массива и указателя тождественны в С++" - это слишком расплывчатая формулировка для того, чтобы к ней придираться, но тем не мнее запомните, что массив не является указателем ни в С, ни в С++. Массив может лишь конвертироваться к указателю, но не более.

Answer (score 2):

[[@00Brain00](/users/22682/00brain00)](/users/22682/00brain00), Вы пишете

```
 Хотя бы дайте общие понятия по логике передачи адреса двумерного и более массива в функцию
```

Элементы классических массивов (независимо от количества измерений) размещаются в памяти последовательно.

Поэтому в общем случае для доступа к элементу с заданными координатами в функцию надо передать адрес первого элемента и размер всех измерений (кроме "верхнего"). В таком случае массив можно рассматривать как одномерный и вычислять индекс нужного элемента в нем.

Для двумерного массива получаем:

```
T get_elem (T *arr, int cols, int n_row, int n_col) // T это тип (в Си можно определять в #define, например, #define T double)
{  
    return arr[n_row * cols + n_col];
}
```

Для трехмерного

```
T get_elem (T *arr, int rows, int cols, int i, int j, int k)
{  
    return arr[i * rows * cols + j * cols + k];
}
```

Далее аналогично.

Если Вы знаете (при написании программы, т.е. знаете константы) размер всех измерений массива, кроме, может быть, самого "верхнего", то компилятор упрощает Вам жизнь и для трехмерного `int arr[][4][3]` можно написать функцию так:

```
 int get_elem (int arr[][4][3], int i, int j, int k) {
    return arr[i][j][k];
 }
```

и, разместив в `main` подходящие массивы, написать что-то вроде

```
  int a[10][4][3], // 10 плоскостей (матриц), каждая из 4-х строк по 3 элемнта
      b[3][4][3];
    ...
  printf ("%d\n", get_elem(a, 2, 2, 2) + get_elem(b, 2, 2, 2));
```

Не забывайте, что все индексы с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

Если размеры массива являются константами времени компиляции (как в вашем примере), то никакого специального огорода с указателями городить не надо

```
const int size1 = 3;
const int size2 = 4;

void arr_fun(const int arr[size1][size2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
           cout << arr[i][j] << endl;
}

...
int arr[size1][size2] = { ... };
arr_fun(arr);
```

Вот и все. Никаких трехэтажных манипуляций с указателями тут не нужно в принципе.

В С++ я бы посоветовал даже передавать массив "по ссылке", чтобы заставить компилятор выполнять жесткую проверку обоих размеров

```
void arr_fun(const int (&arr)[size1][size2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
           cout << arr[i][j] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В очень ограниченном случае можно делать так, как вы хотите:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int n, int m>
void print(const T (&xs)[n][m]) {
    using namespace std;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            cout << xs[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    int as[2][2] = {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
    };

    float bs[2][3] = {
        {2.f, 0.5f, 100.f},
        {1.f, 0.2f, 3.14f},
    };

    print(as);
    print(bs);
}
```

Но это значит, что размер массива должен быть известен на этапе компиляции (точнее, быть `constexpr`), т.к. он является частью типа функции.

Но в практически значимых случаях остается только паковать массив в одномерный самим или использовать какие-то существующие классы для этого.

Answer (score 0):

Двумерный массив передается в функцию так:

```
f(int **arr, ...){...}
void main(){int **arr; f(arr); }
```

Размер как числа (int[5][2]) не передается, числа нужно передавать отдельно. 
Точно так же вы можете передать функцию.

```
int func(){return 5;}
int func2(int f()){...}
void main(){func2(func);}
```

Comment: Обвчный встроенный двумерный массив невозможно непосредственно передать в функцию как `int **`. В вопросе же речь идет именно о встроенном двумерном массиве 'int arr[3][4]`.

Answer (score -1):

В синтаксисе Си отсутствует способ передачи двумерного (или более) массива с переменными размерами. Доступна передача только с фиксированными размерами всех размерностей, кроме последней.

Надо передать указатель (например, на `void`) и все размерности.

Код:

```
double[][10ul][12ul]={...{...{27.6,...}}};
void fun(void *const _p, const size_t _cols, const size_t _depth){
   size_t i=2, j=4, k=5; 
   double *dd = ((double*)_p+((k*_depth)+j)*_cols+i);
   *dd = 1.25;
}
```

Желательно написать некий макрос али инлайн функцию, возвращающую указатель, туда придётся передать 6 параметров, указатель, 3 индекса и 2 размерности.

Если размерность матрицы 4, то 8 параметров, на один индекс больше и на одну размерность и выражение будет посложнее.

Можно конечно двойной или тройной указатель. Там вообще без проблем. Но это накладно, ибо надо выделять место под указатель на строки, на слои и т.д.

В общем, получается много лишних указателей. Эту конструкцию можно выделить одним `malloc` и освободить одним `free`. А там придётся писать многократно вложенные циклы для выделения памяти и освобождения.

Так что хоть выражение и более громоздкое и создаёт ряд небольших проблем, зато позволяет сократить ресурсы и работает лучше, чем многоуровневые указатели.

Comment: Неверно. В синтаксисе Си, разумеется, присутствует возможность передачи многомерных массивов переменного размера. Банальное `void foo(size_t n, size_t m, int array[n][m])` делает именно это. И никаких трюков с указателями не надо. Другое дело, что вопрос явно помечен как С++, а не как С. Поэтому причем тут С - не ясно.